# QR Factorization

Tags: linear-algebra

If A = QR does R(A) = R(Q)?

So far I've come up with R^m = range = R(A)
Then Amxn = (Qmxn)(Rnxn)

After this I get stuck and really have no idea what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by $R(A)$? The row-space of $A$?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean